# How to set the comment body field to be required?

Tags: comments, forms

I have created a comment section in my node. But it is not displaying the required option. if the comment is posted no validation occurs.

Comment: Can i know which version of drupal you are trying ? because in drupal7 comments body field by default is required.

Comment: i'm using drupal 7, but it's not showing by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For What ever content type you are giving comments options, you need to go to

`structure >> Content types >> Edit the particular content type >> there will be comments fields tab >>` over there  will be list of comments field, in that    comment_body(machine name) wil be required by default.

If not, make it required by editing that field.